# how to access scroll bar inside the div using protractor for e2e

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor

im currently writing an e2e script however, im having issues accessing an element when the a div overflows and scrollbar within the div is being activated.

Inside the form, i need to access the scroll down inside the div of the request travel form.

[image]

I tried using:

```
 browser.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,10000);").then(callback);
```

However, the scrollbar that it access is the browser itself not the div i intended to scroll down.

Any leads or suggestion is greatly appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue with my application. There is no direct way using which you can scroll inside scrollbar but I achieved it using javacript executor.

**Option 1:-** 
   You can select element till which you wanted to scroll. 
 example:- (replace  with your actual identifier)

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', <yourelement>.getWebElement());
```

**Option 2:-** 
 Find the identifier of element on which scrollbar is applied and use below code.

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("divExample");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

let me know if still facing issue.

Comment: what is the content of the getWebElement()?

Comment: getWebElement returns the WebElement represented by this ElementFinder.