# Protractor-How to handle horizontal scroll bar in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor tool,Can any one help me to handle horizontal scroll bar in protractor.

i have tried below ways.

browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(10000,0);');

browser.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).scrollRight(arguments[0].scrollRight + 20)", this.btnYearExcel.getWebElement())

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403803/how-to-access-scroll-bar-inside-the-div-using-protractor-for-e2e/53406651#53406651)

Scrolling works in similar fashion for both horizontal/vertical

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But in my application if the scroll bar move then only we can see the element which i wanted to click. the code which you shared will work without moving scroll bar i guess.so it is not helping for my scenario.please help me if any other solution is there

Comment: if you use javascript to scroll, Code will get that element in focus. Meaning if you element is not displayed and you execute "browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', <yourelement>.getWebElement());", It will just scroll both ways to get this element in focus, Next operations like click you need to next to it.

Comment: Then it is not working for me.scroll is not moving :(

Comment: Do you have any sample site available where I can reproduce this scenario?